# Need advice for best practices how to create small website using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to create one small application using asp.net with a login page. After login I want navigation menu items. How do I create these navigation menuitems? I have some ideas in mind using iframe, usercontrols or master page.

Answer (score 1):

You may look into [SiteMap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy2ykkab.aspx)

Also check this tutorial:  [Building our Master Page and Site Navigation Structure](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/17/Data-Tutorial-_2300_2_3A00_-Building-our-Master-Page-and-Site-Navigation-Structure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting started with ASP.NET so depending on which technology you prefer (MVC or Web Forms) either of these two sets of tutorials provided by Microsoft will be of great help.

- MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc
- Web Forms: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials

IMHO you would do well to go with a predefined CSS framework (like [Bootstrap from Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)) and MVC.